# How do I calculate metrics like precision @ 99% recall using sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm trying to calculate metrics like *precision @ 99% recall* for a classifier using sklearn.

`sklearn.metrics` has `precision_score` but it has no way to calculate it for specific values of recall. One way I can think of is to use `precision_recall_curve` and hope that for some *threshold*, recall value happens to be 99%, so that I can use the corresponding precision.

Is there a better way to do this? If not, is there a way I can specify the range/number of thresholds to be used by `precision_recall_curve`?